# Evaluate this series using an integral

Tags: analysis

[image]

I've shown that it converges uniformly but am not sure what to do to evaluate the sum. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

$$(1-x^2)^2x^{n-1}=x^{n-1}-2x^{n+1}+x^{n+3}\implies\int(x^{n-1}-2x^{n+1}+x^{n+3})dx=$$

$$=\frac{x^n}n-\frac{2x^{n+2}}{n+2}+\frac{x^{n+4}}{n+4}+C$$

Now do partial fractions:

$$\frac1{n(n+2)(n+4)}=\frac18\left(\frac1n-\frac2{n+2}+\frac1{n+4}\right)$$